# C# Get specific file Zip azure File Storage

Tags: c#, azure, zip, azure-storage-files

I was wondering if it is possible to get a specific file in a ZIP from Azure File Storage without downloading and unzipping the whole ZIP.

The problem is that the zip file can be large (>1 gb), while the file in the zip which I need is just a few MB tops.

If it is possible, could you provide an example or link(s)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to get a specific file in a ZIP from
>   Azure File Storage without downloading and unzipping the whole ZIP.

No. You would need to download the entire file from storage, unzip the file and then extract the desired file. It is possible to keep the entire downloaded file in memory (in form of stream) and have a zipping library work on that stream instead of saving the entire file on the disk. But you have to read the entire file.

Comment: Too bad to hear. Thank you for your fast response.